# 26 | x only when 2 | x and 13 | x

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Let x some random integer.

How can I prove that 26 | x (26 divides x) only when 2 | x and 13 | x.

I know it´s true and seems logical because 26 is divisible by both 2 and 13, but how can I mathematically prove it using number theory (divisibility)?

Comment: $26 = 2\times 13$ ---- Edit: oh sorry I did not read the full question. I only read the title before I commented this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$26|x$ means $x=26k$.

This implies $x=2\cdot 13k=2k'$ and $x=13\cdot 2k=13k''$,

hence $2|x$ and $13|x$

Answer (score 0):

You can say much more: **Say $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Then $a|n$ and $b|n$ iff $ab|n$.**

Proof: Since $a|n$ we can write $n=ak$. Now since $b|ak$ we have, by Euclid lemma $b|k$, so $k=bl$. Thus $n=abl$ and so $ab|n$.

Vice versa. Say $ab|n$ and since $a|ab$ we have by transitivity $a|n$ and the same holds for $b$.